# Creating VMs from Instance Template on Cloud Function via API call

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, oauth-2.0, google-cloud-functions, google-compute-engine

The code I've written seems to be what I need, however it doesn't work and I get a 401 error (authentication) I've tried everything: 1. Service account permissions 2. create secret id and key (not sure how to use those to get access token though) 3. Basically, tried everything for the past 2 days.

```py
import requests
from google.oauth2 import service_account


METADATA_URL = 'http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/'
METADATA_HEADERS = {'Metadata-Flavor': 'Google'}
SERVICE_ACCOUNT = [NAME-OF-SERVICE-ACCOUNT-USED-WITH-CLOUD-FUNCTION-WHICH-HAS-COMPUTE-ADMIN-PRIVILEGES]


def get_access_token():
    url = '{}instance/service-accounts/{}/token'.format(
        METADATA_URL, SERVICE_ACCOUNT)

    # Request an access token from the metadata server.
    r = requests.get(url, headers=METADATA_HEADERS)
    r.raise_for_status()

    # Extract the access token from the response.
    access_token = r.json()['access_token']

    return access_token

def start_vms(request):
    request_json = request.get_json(silent=True)
    request_args = request.args

    if request_json and 'number_of_instances_to_create' in request_json:
            number_of_instances_to_create = request_json['number_of_instances_to_create']
    elif request_args and 'number_of_instances_to_create' in request_args:
        number_of_instances_to_create = request_args['number_of_instances_to_create']
    else:
        number_of_instances_to_create = 0
    access_token = get_access_token()
    address = "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/[MY-PROJECT]/zones/europe-west2-b/instances?sourceInstanceTemplate=https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/[MY-PROJECT]/global/instanceTemplates/[MY-INSTANCE-TEMPLATE]"
    headers = {'token': '{}'.format(access_token)}
    for i in range(1,number_of_instances_to_create):
        data = {'name': 'my-instance-{}'.format(i)}
        r = requests.post(address, data=data, headers=headers)
        r.raise_for_status()
        print("my-instance-{} created".format(i))
```

Any advice/guidance? If someone could tell me how to get an access token using secret Id and key. Also, I'm not too sure if OAuth2.0 will work because I essentially want to turn these machines on, and they do some processing and then self destruct. So there is no user involvement to allow access. If OAuth2.0 is the wrong way to go about it, what else can I use?

I tried using gcloud, but subprocess'ing gcloud commands aren't recommended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did something similar to this, though I used the Node 10 Firebase Functions runtime, but should be very similar never-the-less.

I agree that OAuth is not the correct solution since there is no user involved.

What you need to use is 'Application Default Credentials' which is based on the permissions available to your cloud functions' default service account which will be the one labelled as "App Engine default service account" here:
https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/serviceaccounts?folder=&organizationId=&project=[YOUR_PROJECT_ID]

(For my project that service account already had the permissions necessary for starting and stopping GCE instances, but for other API's I have grant it permissions manually.)

ADC is for server-to-server API calls.  To use it I called google.auth.getClient (of the Google APIs Auth Library) with just the scope, ie. "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform".

This API is very versatile in that it returns whatever credentials you need, so when I am running on cloud functions it returns a 'Compute' object and when I'm running in the emulator it gives me a "UserRefreshClient" object.

I then include that auth object in my call to compute.instances.insert() and compute.instances.stop().

Here the template I used for testing my code...

```
{
  name: 'base',
  description: 'Temporary instance used for testing.',
  tags: { items: [ 'test' ] },
  machineType: `zones/${zone}/machineTypes/n1-standard-1`,
  disks: [
    {
      autoDelete: true, // you will want this!
      boot: true,
      type: 'PERSISTENT',
      initializeParams: {
        diskSizeGb: '10',
        sourceImage: "projects/ubuntu-os-cloud/global/images/ubuntu-minimal-1804-bionic-v20190628",
      }
    }
  ],
  networkInterfaces: [
    {
    network: `https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/${projectId}/global/networks/default`,
    accessConfigs: [
        {
        name: 'External NAT',
        type: 'ONE_TO_ONE_NAT'
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: That has given me something to think about. However from the perspective of spinning up instances, there are currently three ways:
1. GUI
2. GCloud
3. API

GUI is out, since it's a machine + no user. API seems like it's out, since it needs OAuth2.0 (again no user to authenticate) So that leaves me with gcloud. Is the most sensible approach doing a ```subprocess.call("gcloud compute create...", shell=True)``` or do you reckon there's a better way around it?

Comment: Basically with CloudFunction, how do I point the code to the service account?
```credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_info(service_account_info)``` which is normally ```credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)```

Comment: @daudnadeem You write that API is out since it needs OAuth, but no, I'm saying that API worked fine using ADC auth instead, and ADC auth is much simpler then OAuth to boot.  (Also, I took that to be the question so I was trying to answer the question.)  You don't have to point your code at the service account - it automatically uses the Functions' default service account - it really is as simple as I described it above.  As long as you are running on GCP it seems like a very good method.

Comment: Your answer contained jus enough hints for me to get the job done. Well done, sir.

Answer (score 1):

If you’re getting a 401 error that means that the access token you're using is either expired or invalid.

This guide will be able to show you how to request OAuth 2.0 access tokens and make API calls using a Service Account: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount

The .json file mentioned is the private key you create in IAM & Admin under your service account.